# ANR when user enter many emojis at a time

Tags: android, android-edittext, emoji, android-anr-dialog

I am using a library for displaying emojis,when user enter many emoji the ANR get reproduced is there any way to handle this.This is the library which i am using 
https://github.com/ankushsachdeva/emojicon

Comment: Use strict mode to check where you main thread is getting blocked.

Comment: okay will try this thanks :)